# angularjs $resource not replacing variable in url template for POST

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

Using AngularJS 1.2.16 and angular-resource 1.2.16.

I have a resource like:

```
$resource('api/:variable/path',
    {
        variable:'@variableName'
    });
```

When I do a get using something like

```
resourceIns.get({variable:'taco'});
```

The resulting ajax call replaces :variable properly and i get

```
api/taco/path
```

If I do a post like

```
resourceIns.save({variable:'taco'});
```

the resulting ajax call looks like

```
api/path
```

and 'taco' gets put in the POST body...

I've had trouble finding others complaining about this so, maybe this is what's supposed to happen?

edit: I just discovered that get uses 'variable' and save/POST uses 'variableName' in the above example. Anybody have an explanation for that?

Here's a fiddle showing the situation: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6he3H/1/)

Comment: I don't think I've ever used a config where the parameter and field names were different. I'd also expect `resourceIns.get({variableName:'taco'});` to work and not the other way around.

Comment: @HackedByChinese - It's looking like using the same field names would be a good practice. I mostly think it's weird that it appears to be completely swapped for the different cases. I would expect to be able to change a get to a save and have the only change be from a GET to a POST...

Comment: I agree. I'll look at the source, perhaps it's a bug in `.get()`.

Answer (score 3):

I ran across the same issue or one that presented itself in the same fashion. My resource, too, was not respecting parameters passed in through a .post method.

I was able to get it to work by **directly passing in the expected parameters**.

Using a $resource:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('ModuleProductProducts', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/module-api/product-products/:siteId/:id/:controller', {
      id: '@id'
    },
    {
        'updateMedia': {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'module-api/product-products/:id/media/:mediaId',

            // *** Here ***
            params: {
                id: '@id',
                mediaId: '@mediaId'
            }
            // ************
        }
    });
  });
```