# How to use restful instead of query syntax for this $resource factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

So I've got a $resource factory like so:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    app.factory('WidgetFactory', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:8282/widget/:widgetId', { widgetId : '@id'},{
                rate: {method:'POST', params:{applyRating:true}}
            });
    }]);
}());
```

Then in my controller I want to get the widget with id 1:

```
this._widgets = WidgetFactory.get({ id:1 }); // or WidgetFactory.query({ id:1 })
```

But my then the request goes out as `http://localhost:8282/widget?id=1` instead of `widget/1`

How to formulate the request the $resource from the controller to produce `widget/1`? I guess my noob question is how do I pass-in `'@id'` parameter when using my resource factory (how does `'@id'` really work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be best to match paramDefault key/value, for reasons just recently described in [angularjs $resource not replacing variable in url template for POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025749/angularjs-resource-not-replacing-variable-in-url-template-for-post)

So, then if your $resource config looks like

```
app.factory('WidgetFactory', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8282/widget/:widgetId', { widgetId : '@widgetId'},{
            rate: {method:'POST', params:{applyRating:true}}
        });
}]);
```

your controller call would look like

```
this._widgets = WidgetFactory.get({ widgetId:1 });
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/W9aeaZJpjqfcePRhZzLS?p=preview)